# Obtain buffer file name without extension in .emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am trying to make shortcuts for portable emacs linking to a portable LaTeX compiler and R for Sweave, but I know very little about the language used in `.emacs` (this is Lisp?)

Currently I am using `fullpath-relative-to-current-file` obtained from [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_relative_path.html) to get the path to `.emacs` (which is in `USBDRIVE/Documents`), then get the relative path to the compiler and call it on `buffer-file-name` which is the full path and filename including extension of the extension:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
            (cond ((string-equal (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name)) "tex") 
                (shell-command (concat (fullpath-relative-to-current-file "../PortableApps/miktex/miktex/bin/pdflatex ") buffer-file-name)))
            )
            (cond ((string-equal (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name)) "Rnw") 
                (shell-command (concat (fullpath-relative-to-current-file "../PortableApps/R/R-2.14.1/bin/R CMD Sweave ") buffer-file-name " --pdf")))
            )
        )
)
```

This allows me to use `C-c s` to run LaTeX on a `tex` file and `Sweave` on an Rnw file. Now I would like to include calls to bibtex, but for that I need the filename and path of the `tex` file without extension. How can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `file-name-sans-extension`.  For more details, read the [File Name Components](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html) section of the manual.

Comment: Thanks. `(file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)` worked.